# Bringing subview in front of keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a page in which I am sending a message. I have a `UIView`, with an `UIActivityIndicatorView`, which appears at the center of the screen when I click "send" and then disappears on delivery. This view is being hidden by the keyboard. I want to know how to bring it in front of the keyboard because `[UIView bringSubviewtoFront]` doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If this view needs to block some portion of your keyboard then I'm assuming at that point you don't need the keyboard. If you don't need the keyboard you should dismiss it using `[someTextView resignFirstResponder];`

pro-tip - in IOS, when you gotta bend over backwards to do something, you are probably doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Note: to make the keyboard appear again after the user re-opens the app use `[someTextView becomeFirstResponder];`

Comment: Hmm. I considered hiding the keyboard too, but thats not what I'm looking to do. I guess I'll just have to move the whole view above the keyboard itself if there is no other way. :/

Comment: there are other ways... its just not ideal

Comment: One can be ambitious though. ;)

Comment: btw, here is my fav article for managing keyboard - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Answer (score 2):

This code Worked for me try it. hope it will helps you

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject;
[window addSubview:self.view];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[window bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
```